# Пример альтернативы метода поиска в массиве, для оптимизации использования данных браузера?

Tags: javascript

Напишите пример альтернативы метода поиска в массиве, для оптимизации использования данных браузера:

const temporaryData = [{a: 10, b: true}, {a: 15, b: false}, {a: 10, b: false}…]

temporaryData.find( el => el?.a === 10)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: а что сейчас не так? какие проблемы с браузером?

Comment: как переписать это с помощью filter ?

Comment: Почему обяхательно с помощью filter? И почему filter - это "оптимизация использования данных браузера" ? На чём это основано? И почему текущий вариант "не оптимизирован"?

Answer (score -2):

Я не совсем тоже понял в чем проблема, но написал такое решение вот:

```js
const temporaryData = [{ a: 10, b: true }, { a: 15, b: false }, { a: 10, b: false }]

const amount = temporaryData.reduce(function (newArr, num) {
  if (num.a === 10) {
    newArr.push(num.a);
  }
  return newArr;
}, []);

console.log(amount);
```